# Mixed partial derivative product rule

Tags: combinatorics, partial-derivative

I just found a formula (Proposition 5 in http://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/v13i1r1) that states the product rule for a mixed partial derivative of a product of two functions. Is there something similar for a product of $n$ functions? That is,

$\frac{\partial^n}{\partial x_1 \dots \partial x_n} \prod_{i=1}^n f_i(x_1,\dots,x_n) = $ ?

Comment: The formula for a product of two functions can be applied recursively to a product of several functions.  There seems no special reason to apply the rule for exactly $n$ functions multiplied when $n$ is at the same time the number of distinct variables in a mixed partial derivative.

Comment: Just such an approach for ordinary derivatives, invoking multinomial coeffcients in place of the binomial coefficients of Leibniz's rule, can be found in the Wikipedia article [General Leibniz rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule).